# Foreign Key based dropdowns show same value in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

**Background:**

I'm building a Django forms based application. The form has dropdowns for which the values comes from another table(model). I read somewhere that using foreign key you can make dynamic dropdowns for which the value comes from the source table.

**Problem:**

All the dropdowns show same value. For example: If I put values in national, aetna, kaiser, bcbs,tufts as A,B,C,D,E then in all the dropdowns rendered on webpage , there is B as the option while it should have been A for first dropdown, B for second and so on.
[image: This is the screenshot of the webpage]

Why is this happening?

**Code:**

**models.py**:

Model 1 from which data would be shown:

```
class RiskBand(models.Model):
    """Model to store Risk band data"""
    national = models.CharField(
            'National Risk Band',
            max_length=50,
            null=True,
            unique=True  # Required attribute for it to be used as FK
            )
    aetna = models.CharField(
            'Aetna Risk Band',
            max_length=50,
            null=True,
            unique=True
            )
    kaiser = models.CharField(
            'Kaiser Risk Band',
            max_length=50,
            unique=True
            )
    bcbs = models.CharField(
            'BCBS Risk Band',
            max_length=50,
            unique=True
            )
    tufts = models.CharField(
            'TUFTS Risk Band',
            max_length=50,
            unique=True
            )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.aetna
```

Model 2 where data would be shown:

```
class ClientRiskBand(TimeStampedModel):
    """Model to store Risk bands for a client set by an underwriter"""
    YEAR_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(1984, datetime.date.today().year+10)]
    year = models.IntegerField(
            'Year',
            choices=YEAR_CHOICES,
            default=datetime.datetime.now().year
            )
    client_name = models.CharField(
            'Client Name',
            max_length=100,
            )
    # Todo : Add sales person field with foreign key from users table
    aetna1 = models.ForeignKey(
            'RiskBand',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            to_field='aetna',
            related_name='aetna1',
            verbose_name='Select Aetna Risk Band 1'
            )
    aetna2 = models.ForeignKey(
            'RiskBand',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            to_field='aetna',
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects
            related_name='aetna_reverse',
            verbose_name='Select Aetna Risk Band 2'
            )
    kaiser = models.ForeignKey(
            'RiskBand',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            to_field='kaiser',
            related_name='kaiser_reverse',
            verbose_name='Select Kaiser Risk Band'
            )
    bcbs = models.ForeignKey(
            'RiskBand',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            to_field='bcbs',
            related_name='bcbs_reverse',
            verbose_name='Select BCBS Risk Band'
            )
    tufts = models.ForeignKey(
            'RiskBand',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            to_field='tufts',
            related_name='tufts_reverse',
            verbose_name='Select TUFTS Risk Band'
            )
    national1 = models.ForeignKey(
            'RiskBand',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            to_field='national',
            related_name='national1_reverse',
            verbose_name='Select National Risk Band 1'
            )
    national2 = models.ForeignKey(
            'RiskBand',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            to_field='national',
            related_name='national2_reverse',
            verbose_name='Select National Risk Band 2'
            )

    class META:
        verbose_name = 'Risk Bands for Client'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Risk Bands for Clients'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client_name
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ClientRiskBandForm(ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
    helper.field_class = 'col-lg-10'
    helper.layout = Layout(
            'year',
            'client_name',
            'aetna1',
            'aetna2',
            'kaiser',
            'bcbs',
            'tufts',
            'national1',
            'national2',
            FormActions(
                Submit(
                    'save_changes', 'Save Changes', css_class='btn-success'
                    ),
                Submit(
                    'cancel', 'Cancel', css_class='btn-default'),
                    ),
            )

    class Meta:
        model = ClientRiskBand
        fields = {
                'year', 'client_name', 'aetna1', 'aetna2',
                'kaiser', 'bcbs', 'tufts', 'national1', 'national2'
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct display. There is only one single `RiskBand` instance and this is offered by the dropdowns (All the fields are foreign keys to the same model, the purpose of which is quite obscure to me).

The dropdown does not display the values of the specified `to_field`, but `str(instance)` (or `unicode(instance)`). The way you have implemented `RiskBand.__str__`, the dropdown will therefore always show the `aetna` value of the available `RiskBand` instances, regardless of the `to_field`.

Comment: But, why is that? I thought `to_field` would connect specific field that I mentioned and it would show that field data in the dropdown in forms.

Comment: I understood now that django doesn't return to_field values but the one you specify in __str__ method. You would need to use other methods to achieve this kind of functionality.